# How define a size for image with AsyncImage

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

**The problem:**
When i use AsyncImage to display an image. The size of image is big and dont fit the size of frame.

Thats the code i used:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: mockImageUrl))
        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
```

And this is how image is displayed:

[image on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r2Db.png)

**What I need:**
I need to do image fits the frame.

**What I tryed:**
I defined the size of AsyncImage but the image still doesnt feat the height and width of frame.

Comment: see the example given by Apple at:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage

Comment: thank you, the documentation was not very clear about the size of the image, I forgot to say I read it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

To make image follow the size of AsyncImage you need change the scale of image like this:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: mockImageUrl)){ result in
            result.image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

".resizable()" code allow the image size fit the frame of AsyncImage.

[image on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6KDl.png)

**Documentation examples:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage

Comment: yes, just like I said in my comment, `see the example given by Apple`